# PyCharm code completion treats function reference as a field and not as a function

Tags: python, pycharm

In the below example:

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("My Tkinter")
```

If I try code completion (Ctrl+Space) at *window.titl* PyCharm suggest *title* as field(f) and not as method(m) or function(F). As *title* is a function reference for wm_title(), I wonder why PyCharm behaves like that.

However in Pydev it suggest as *title(string)*. So even a new programmer in python knows that it is a function have one parameter as string.

Is this correct behaviour of code completion in PyCharm ? Is there any way to achieve the code completion like that of PyDev especially in this case?

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour. [Link to the symbols.](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/symbols.html)

Comment: The reason is that `title` defined as target with function `wm_title` assigned. Please file an issue in the [tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY)